# Adding ylim changes where the mean point is plotted in violinplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, point, violin-plot

I am trying to do a violinplot for a single variable and drawing its mean as a point. I manage to do so as follows, for example, with the following data the mean is 0.06 and it woks fine:

```
vble <- c(-1.6666667, NA, -0.2777778, 0.5555556, -2.7777778 , 1.1111111, -0.1587302, NA, NA, 0.0000000, 2.2222222, -1.6666667, 1.1111111, NA, NA, -2.2222222, NA, 4.4444444)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:length(vble), vble)
m <- mean(subsetgr$new, na.rm = TRUE)
m
p = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = "", y = vble)) +
  geom_violin(fill = "#C77CFF")  +   stat_summary(fun = "mean",
                                                geom = "point",
                                                color = "black")
p+ geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image: Correctly portrayed]

As you can see, the point is above the horizontal line over 0.

However, when I adjust the y limits:

```
p + lims(y = c(-5, 3)) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

the point is plotted below such line.
[image: Incorrectly portrayed]

I need to adjust the y limits, what do you suggest that I do so that the mean point is correctly plotted?

Thank you very much!

---

*Edit*
The following solutions, suggested in comments, are also not what I am looking for:

```
p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-5, 3))+ geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

coord_cartesian keeps the average point in the correct place but does not adapt the figure to the new y-axis and therefore, it does not fit
[image: opt3]

```
p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5,3)) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

scale_y_continuous also deletes data and this changes where the average point is portrayed

[image: opt4]

And adding the argument "oob" also brings the same issue

```
p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5,3), oob = scales::oob_keep) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image: opt5]

Is there a way to manually plot a point in the violinplot. It is not ideal, but I would have to do it only 10 times, for 10 plots, so it should be fine.

Comment: If the y-limits are narrower than the data range, data that is out-of-bounds get discarded, which affects the mean calculation. You can try setting the y-limits in `coord_cartesian()` or use `scale_y_continuous(limits = ..., oob = scales::oob_keep)`.

Comment: Hello, I have tried your suggestions but none of them works in order to keep the point in the right place and zoom out the y-axis as I would like to do. I have edited the questions with the attempts. Thank you!

Comment: You cannot selectively enforce limits on one layer and not the others without manual intervention. It is just part of ggplot2's design to make it more difficult to do what is generally considered the wrong thing (e.g. showing a summary for a different part of the data than is displayed).